# Is there a better way to manage a grid based game, other than 3 dimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I am designing a game which will be played on a 8 x 8 grid. Each 'cell' on the grid is a room. A room can have walls or a door on each side ( N, S, E, W ).

That means that a room with a wall will share that wall with the adjacent cell. For example...

[image: Grid and Walls Pic]

As you see, that one wall is affecting two cells.

So how do I manage these cells, and where the walls and doors are? So far, this is what I have:

```
board[2][3][2] = 1;
board[2][4][0] = 1;

// [x][y][d] where direction is 0=N, 1=E, 2=S, 3=W
// Values: 0 = open (nothing there), 1 = wall, 2=door
```

Is this way efficient? Is there a better way of achieving the same result? Every time I set a wall, I have to do it twice. That just feels inefficient.

Thanks!

Comment: You could store only walls on north or west edges. To check for a wall on the east edge, you'd just check the west edge of the room to the east.

That wouldn't work for the south or east edge rooms though (where there is no room to the east or to the south)

Comment: @Skeets Yes it would. You'd just have to increase the array for the walls by a row and a column.

Comment: @Thomas oh, good point.

Comment: Use a separate object type for each “box”. If the properties are all initially setup this is well-optimized in mainstream browsers. *A separate defined object type also greatly simplifies the code.* For an 8x8 grid the problem space is trivial.

Comment: That is, “room[x][y].east == WALL” might be a valid check. It’s also readable, can be extended, and is much easier to debug. Access to the (now) 2d array should itself be minimized to the essential ‘internal’ methods.

Comment: For a MUCH larger problem space, a different approach might be warranted. This is not it. It is also possible to perform micro-optimizations (packing, instance sharing, bitmapping, flatting to a single array): and *none of these matter here*.

Comment: If one was interested in the walls as discreet and shared objects, consider an interleaved grid where it is “wall..room..wall..room..wall”. Then rooms are identified by (x * 2 + 1, y * 2 + 1) coordinates. Each cell (in the 2d matrix) would still contain an applicable object type. This same approach can also be represented in a grid of rooms and a grid of walls. Abstractions can be done in both cases. Alternatively, the “east” property, eg., of a room could refer to the same object (of a ‘wall’ type) as the “west” property of an adjacent room to enable sharing.

Comment: If the problem calls for “just walls”, then it may be begging for a different structure entirely, such a connected sets of coordinates, depending on operations.. and once again, this is not the case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You can just store north and west walls***. For south walls, check the north wall of the cell to the south, for east walls, check the west wall of the cell to the east.

I at first thought this would be a problem for cells on the south and east edges, but if you just make your wall array go beyond the building array by one cell in the south and east directions, this will work. (thanks @Thomas in the comments section of OP for the tip)

This way, you can still refer to walls easily by the cell they are near, but you only need to store each wall once.

### Storing walls

Supposing north is `0` and west is `1`:

```
 
|
```

So this wall would be:

`board[1][1][1]=1`

### To check for walls:

Suppose the player is in cell 1,1.

- If moving north: check cell 1,1 for a north wall.
- If moving south: check the cell 1,2 for a north wall.
- if moving west: check cell 1,1 for a west wall.
- if moving east: check cell 2,1 for a west wall.

Comment: Well, the question actually was about if there is a better way than a 3-dimensional array, and this answer just only optimized the usage of this 3-dimensional array but it's not answering the question.

Comment: Don't read the question title and assume you've read the whole question  If you read the whole question, you'll find the OP is mostly concerned that each wall needs to be set twice.

Answer (score 1):

In term or performance you will get better resulta using a bi-dimensional array and reffer to the walls using a object with four bool properties (one for each wall)

Comment: And flexibility and readability..

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the array guaranteeing a contigous memory location the formula if I remember correctly is something like `width * row + col`. There is an `array.flatten()` method also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your rooms in the grid, store the connections,

In a simplified grid:

```
[a][b][c]     
[d][e][f]  
[g][h][i]
```

Currently you are storing: 
a[north], a[east], a[west], a[south] which requires 36 elements.

Instead try ab, bc, ad, be, cf, de, ... which would store 12 elements

Furthermore, you could only store doors in your array and assume if not present you are a wall (depending on out of bounds rules)

Comment: This ain't the simplest, but the most flexible approach. Storing the doors as edges on a graph of nodes can easily be expanded to things like tunnels, portals or teleports where you can move to a non adjecent-cell or things that can be passed only in one direction. And this is a great data-structure if you'll ever want to deal with pathfinding, like for enemies that are chasing you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, think of using an orthornormed coordinate system, that is to say you define the x and y axes for example on the top left corner.
So a wall becomes a segment with a starting point and a finishing point.
So referencing your cell becomes this:

```
    cellBegin = board[2][4];
    cellEnd = board[3][4];
```